# Where clause php is not working

Tags: php, mysql

this is my 1st php on the 1st place. if there is anything wrong with i did please help me with code. since i just started learning. i tried with so many tutorials but i was unable to undestand what im doing wrong.

```
 <?php

include "db_config.php";

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM places WHERE place_id ='".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST[place_id])."'");

while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
        $output[]=$e;

echo $row['name'];

mysql_close();
?>
```

Is this correct?
im not sure how it is working.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE $_REQUEST[place_id]");
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: If this is your first php program do yourself a favor and stop using the deprecated mysql_ family of calls.  Switch to mysqli_ or better still, PDO.

Comment: Another reason to not use the `mysql_*` functions: You need to take care of passing the results around. PDO is much more comfortable here, you can use it with `foreach` which reduces the places where you can make such errors.

Comment: if `place_id` is numerical - you should remove the quotes that currently surround it too

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 4):

You have a typo on this line:

```
 while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
```

`$q` needs to be `$query`. I do not see a variable `$q` in your code. This is a common problem in php code as if you introduce a name like `$q` php is "nice" enough to create the variable for you and initialize it to `null` instead of sanely giving you an error.

Comment: That's not the only mistake in that (short) script.

Answer (score 2):

You need to privode mysql_fetch_assoc() with the results of mysql_query, here $query.

```
<?php

include "db_config.php";

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM places WHERE place_id='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[place_id])."'");

while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    $output[]=$e;

print(json_encode($output));

mysql_close();
?>
```

Moreover, you need to use some pdo or mysqli since mysql_ are deprecated: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php